# vim clang_complete debian doesn't work - how to install it properly?

Tags: c, linux, vim, vim-plugin

I am a linux beginner and just wanted to start coding in C/learn something about sockets, but as it turned out I had to spend 6 hours on trying to install clang_complete for vim instead.

Here is what I've done:

1. **cd** ~/Downloads && git clone https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/wiki
2. **make install**
3. **apt-get install** libclang1-3.9
4. **cd** /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu **&& ln -s** libclang-3.9.so.1 libclang.so
5. **vim** /etc/vim/vimrc
6. appended **let** g:clang_library_path = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' to this vimrc
7. **vim** test.c => *nothing happens/no auto completion or anytihng.*

I really don't know what I am doing wrong and out of breathe. Please help me, I used google and found a lot but all I have tried failed so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an `auto-complete` plugin for `vim`, try this : [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe).

This is one of the best (and kind of must-install) plugins out there for vim. It offers auto-complete for all the `C-family` as well as other languages as well.